# (Windows) Creating a new user in postgres9.4 with login, createdb, and createrole, but cannot login?

Tags: postgresql

```
C:\Users\Thomas>psql -U Thomas -h localhost
Password for user Thomas:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Thomas"
```

I can login fine using the posgres role. Have reassigned the password to user Thomas like five times ... it just doesn't sit in. What could possibly be wrong here ?

EDIT:
if I try to login as 'thomas' the ERROR becomes:

```
C:\Users\Thomas>psql -U thomas -h localhost
Password for user thomas:
psql: FATAL:  database "thomas" does not exist
```

The \du lists as follows:

```
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 thomas    | Create role, Create DB                         | {}
```

EDIT 2:
If I GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE thomastest TO thomas
Then it is possible to login but it needs extra info in the command line:

```
C:\Users\Thomas>psql -d thomastest -U thomas -h localhost
```

Is it possible to set this as the default login for this user ?

Comment: can you add the output of the `\du` command?

Comment: Is the user named `Thomas` or `thomas` in the system?

Comment: @CraigRinger: That is another thing. I create the user as 'Thomas', but \du lists 'thomas'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set this as the default login for this user ?

Yes, by setting the necessary [environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html):

- `PGUSER` for the default user
- `PGDATABASE` for the default database

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your pg_hba.conf file. psql uses domain sockets to connect to your database, which is different than what a program would do when coming from the outside. At the very top of the security declarations, you probably have something like:

`local   all   all    ident`

change that to:

`local   all   all    md5`

or, if you feel like it wouldn't be a security concern:

`local   all   all    trust`

`md5` will prompt for a password. `trust` will just let you in.

Oh, the reason that adding `-h` *kinda* works is because with `-h`, it uses the `host` entries in pg_hba.conf (not over local sockets), which are probably set to `md5`.

When you modify pg_hba, you either need to bounce postgres or run `pg_ctl -D (whatever) reload`

Comment: Also, if you want to change it for just `thomas`, you would put `local   all   thomas    md5`  ABOVE the `local  all  all  ident`  line.

Comment: Looking at the conf file for the first time everything was set to 'host all all md5'. Should I change 'host' to 'local' ? Can I edit this file directly or is it bad practice to touch it ?

Comment: you should add a line for `local   all  all  trust` or `md5`. That allows you to leverage anything that uses local domain sockets (like psql) instead of host (like specifying the -h flag in psql). It's totally OK to edit this file. In fact, I would say it's a best practice to understand it well and apply it to your particular business needs. Just remember you have to pg_ctl -D (whatever) reload or bounce postgres before the changes take effect.

Comment: Right now it works without touching the pg_hda.conf file. If I do touch the file and add a line to it, then the login fails again with FATAL: could not load pg_hda.conf. If I delete the extra line it works again. The offending line is: local all all md5.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. You are running Windows, which doesn't support domain sockets. Ugh. In pg 9.1 (I think) they changed it so that such a config causes errors on Windows. Totally my bad here. It's still good advice to understand pg_hba.conf. But it's also a good idea for commenters on Stack Overflow to actually read which OS you're running. Definitely DON'T add entries for `local` unless you're running linux.

Comment: Don't worry about it man, I am more than happy that you invested some thought in my issue to begin with. I am up and running thanks to all the comments here.